# Discord.py is there a way to check if a message has a reply?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to get all reply to a certain message.id but i simply don't know how.
I want to check if a message has a reply, and if it does return the reply message id/id's to be able to delete them.
Haven't found anything similar yet.
Made it work within the `async def on_member_update(before,after):`

```py
 mention = [message async for message in channel.history(limit=None) if message.author == client.user]
          for reply in mention: 
            if after.mention in reply.content:
              await reply.delete()
```

Comment: You can't easily find this. Discord doesn't store it, and so the API doesn't return it. The only possible way is going through the entire message history, but most channels are too big for that to be an option.

Comment: @stijndcl I tried that, go through the message history, and i can get all replies in that channel. But i can't get where the the message is bound to. It just give me a list of message_id.

Comment: And then you can turn those into messages using fetch_message

Comment: @stijndcl think i found a work around, just mention the user in the reply. Then it's easier to find again

Comment: I don't see how that makes it easier to find? If you mention the user then you only know the user, not the message. That only makes it harder to find it. If you use the actual reply (which tells you the id of the original message) then all you have to do is use `fetch_message` to get it.

Comment: @stijndcl You can use `message.mentions.id`

Comment: Yes but so what? You said you wanted to find the original **message**, I don't see how a mention is useful for that...

Comment: @stijndcl made it work i edit the code in the question